# Root volume /dev/mapper/centos-root full

Tags: centos, hard-drive

On one of my host, i have /dev/mapper/centos-root reporting almost full (99%), here is output of df -h.

==

```
[root@LA3QSSD02-20217 /]# df -h
Filesystem                                       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root                           50G   50G  540M  99% /
devtmpfs                                          63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                             63G   64K   63G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                             63G   18M   63G   1% /run
tmpfs                                             63G     0   63G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdy1                                        494M  210M  285M  43% /boot
/dev/mapper/centos-home                          411G   33M  411G   1% /home
/dev/mapper/datastore-datastore                   11T  548G  9.1T   6% /datastore 
/dev/mapper/data-sdx                             734G   73M  734G   1% /data-sdx 
/dev/mapper/data-sdf                             734G   73M  734G   1% /data-sdf
/dev/mapper/data0                                734G   80M  734G   1% /data0 
/dev/mapper/data-sdd                             734G   73M  734G   1% /data-sdd 
/dev/mapper/data-sdt                             734G   73M  734G   1% /data-sdt 
/dev/mapper/data-sdg                             734G   73M  734G   1% /data-sdg 
/dev/mapper/data-sdu                             734G   73M  734G   1% /data-sdu 
/dev/mapper/data-sdb                             734G   73M  734G   1% /data-sdb
10.253.48.21:/vol/eq1ag4rdtest01/kvm_ostemplates 3.0T  1.8T  1.3T  58% /vol/eq1ag4rdtest01/kvm_ostemplates
tmpfs                                             13G     0   13G   0% /run/user/0
```

==

Im unable to find out what is causing / to report full, here is some more details.

++++

## du -sh *

```
0       bin
229M    boot
5.5M    data0
0       data-sdb
0       data-sdc
0       data-sdd
0       data-sde
0       data-sdf
0       data-sdg
0       data-sdh
0       data-sdi
0       data-sdj
0       data-sdk
0       data-sdl
0       data-sdm
0       data-sdn
0       data-sdo
0       data-sdp
0       data-sdq
0       data-sdr
0       data-sds
0       data-sdt
0       data-sdu
0       data-sdv
0       data-sdw
0       data-sdx
698G    datastore
152K    dev
24M     etc
320K    home
0       lib
0       lib64
0       media
0       mnt
171M    opt
0       proc
160M    root
115M    run
0       sbin
20K     sharedstore
0       srv
0       sys
40K     tmp
2.6G    usr
1.8G    var
1.7T    vol
```

+++++

Please help me in find out what is consuming space on / and how to free it.

Thanks

Regards
Aun

Comment: Have deleted any file that hold by a running process, you can check by executing ''lsof | grep deleted'', and restart process if any

Answer (score 1):

It is possible data exists in the mount points and was hidden when the file systems were mounted.

On Linux you can show what is there with a bind mount.

```
mkdir /mnt/root  
mount --bind / /mnt/root 
du -s /mnt/root/*
```

Conveniently under here every other file system is just an empty mount point so you can just sum up everything.

Answer (score 0):

The files removed by any application or any user (think `rm` command) do **not** release the space, until the file is closed by all the applications (processes) that have it open. Use `lsof2` and look for deleted files, restart the applications that are keeping them open.

Comment: killed processes and rebooted host as well, still same!